# Accessing User-Defined Functions in Google Cloud Functions (ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-source-repositories

I am trying to access user-defined functions outside the deployment folder in Google Cloud Functions deployed on Source Control, but can't find a way to do it properly.

### Folder structure

```
Source repo
├── package
|   └──common_functions.py
├── function1
|   ├──main.py
|   └──requirements.txt
...
└── functionN
    ├──main.py
    └──requirements.txt
```

where I need to import functions from `package/common_functions.py` in every `main.py`.

If I specify `/function1` as the directory for a Google Cloud Function, `from ..package import common_functions.py` will return the following error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

### What works but is not efficient

The following folder structure would works, but is painful in terms of maintenance. If I make a change on one of the common functions, I would need to change all my `common_functions.py` files.

```
Source repo
├── function1
|   ├──main.py
|   ├──requirements.txt
|   └── package
|       └──common_functions.py
...
└── functionN
    ├──main.py
    ├──requirements.txt
    └── package
        └──common_functions.py
```

### Question

Is there any way of importing a file from outside the deployment folder on GCF?

Comment: What parent folder? When you deploy your function's code, there is no parent folder that your code can reference. You must deploy `package` as part of your deployment as listed in your second example. For my deployments, I add a script to copy dependencies to the deployment folder structure.

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley copying dependencies to the deployment folder structure should work. Do you think you could share the script here?

Comment: I use the xcopy command

Comment: @JohnHanley do you have GCF that copies the folder, commits and pushes or are you just doing this from your machine?

Comment: Deployment happens on my machine.

Comment: Ok I'm trying to find a way to do it from GCF

Comment: GCF does not deploy Functions. You deploy either from your desktop or from Cloud Build or from a custom pipeline.

Comment: The second option you are listing is the best approach, there are various tools which can help you with the maintenance such as having your code in a [Cloud Source repository](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/deploying-functions-from-source-repositories) which would make it easier to manage.